# Fetch Is Crashing App on ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my `viewDidLoad`, I have `self.todaySession = (id)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];` which works fine when it finds this object.  But when it doesn't, it crashes the app.  Is there a logic statemnt I can do to fix this?

Comment: put it inside @try then catch the exception ant treat that well.

Comment: **exception handling**? didn't you tried it ever?

Comment: Yes, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this depending on the context.

You can use the count of `fetchedObjects` or `sections` from the `NSFetchedResultsController`. Make sure you call `performFetch:` beforehand.

```
    [fetchedResultsController performFetch:self];

    // Option 1
    BOOL someResultsReturned = ([[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0);
    // Option 2
    BOOL someResultsReturned = ([[fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0);

    if (someResultsReturned) {
        self.todaySession = (id)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    } else {
        // Handle no results here
    }
```

**More Information**

[Read more about NSFetchedResultsController here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).